# 2013 REST api $skiptoken with $orderby returns wrong number of results

Tags: 2013, rest, odata

I noticed some discrepancies in the number of results when getting paged list items when I `$orderBy` different fields.

I set up a test list with 196 items, the below snippet will get items in batches of 50 and when all done will log the total number of items returned.

If I `$orderBy` : `Id` or completely omit `$orderBy`,  I get the correct overall item count (196).

If I `$orderBy` : `Group`, the overall item count will be 144. (In this case, the Group column contains non-unique values, if the Group column contained unique values, it would get the correct count, 196) The API generated `__next` looks OK, but clearly something is going wrong with the paging logic.

Any suggestions? Am I right to just pass `__next` to the next request, without the original params? They seems to be already included in `__next`.

```
(function () {

    var url = '../_api/web/lists/getByTitle(\'Test\')/items',
        getItemsDfd = $.Deferred(),
        params = {
            '$select': 'Title',
            '$orderBy': 'Id', // ok
            //'$orderBy': 'Group', // bad
            '$top': 50
        },
        count = 0;

    function getItems(url, params) {

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: params,
            headers: {
                'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
            },
            success: function (data) {

                console.log('Url requested', decodeURIComponent(this.url));

                count += data.d.results.length;
                if (data.d.__next) {
                    // for the next batch, use the
                    // url the api returns
                    getItems(data.d.__next);
                } else {
                    // when __next is undefined
                    // we have reached the end
                    getItemsDfd.resolve(count);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    // kick off batch operation
    getItems(url, params);

    getItemsDfd.done(function (count) {
        console.log('Item count', count);
    });

}());
```

Comment: Also happening here. The results returned from ODATA query is not the same as when you apply same settings to list view (i.e. ordering with paging, the second page results are different from ODATA's). Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem.
It seems like SharePoint (2019) is having troubles with paging in combination with $orderby.
In my case it was a list of names and there were 3 items with "Sophie" as title.
The list is ordered by title and the first page ends after the first 2 "Sophie" items.
The next page starts with the first "Sophie" despite it already being in the first page.
Additionally sorting by ID did fix the problem for me.

```
let d1 = await $.ajax({url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+ "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Names')/items?$orderby=Title asc",headers:{ accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" }})
let d2 = await $.ajax({url:d1.d.__next,headers:{ accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" }})
console.log(d1.d.results.map(_=>_.Title+_.ID))
console.log(d2.d.results.map(_=>_.Title+_.ID))
/*results in 
...
98: "Sophie92"
99: "Sophie56"
---- next page
0: "Sophie92"
1: "Sophie 137"
...
*/

d1 = await $.ajax({url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+ "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Names')/items?$orderby=Title,ID asc",headers:{ accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" }})
d2 = await $.ajax({url:d1.d.__next,headers:{ accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" }})
console.log(d1.d.results.map(_=>_.Title+_.ID))
console.log(d2.d.results.map(_=>_.Title+_.ID))
/*results in 
...
98: "Sophie56"
99: "Sophie92"
---- next page
0: "Sophie137"
1: "Theresa133"
...
*/
```